# How do I connect AD9601 to stm32f429?

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I have a problem in connecting an ADC (AD9601) to an stm32f429.

I can see three 12-bit ADCs on stm32. But I am stuck in connecting this external ADC to the microcontroller.

Need help to proceed forward.

Comment: Stuck where? What have you done so far? What help specifically you need?

Comment: Do you really need what the AD9601 can do?  10 bit ADC at up to 250MHz, parallel output.  That thing can digitize radio signals.  The output as 10 parallel bits seems like a really bad match to your STM32.

Comment: @JRE Yes i opted this ADC because of its sampling rate and used for RF signals in a receiver circuit.

Comment: @Justme I am not able to figure out its interfacing with microcontroller.

Comment: [I don't think you can (or should) connect it directly to your processor.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-835.pdf)  That is an application note that describes how Analog connects to their own ADC evaluation boards.  There's an FPGA in the middle that handles the high speed stuff.

Comment: Consider for a moment:  The AD9601 can sample 10bits at 250MHz.  That's 500 megabytes per second.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it arrises from a fundamentally mistaken part selection.  There is no practical answer other than "chose other parts" which would be an entirely different question.

Answer (score 1):

[Application note AN-835 from Analog](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-835.pdf) shows how they connect fast, parallel output ADCs for testing.

This is a block diagram from AN-835 showing an evaluation board for an ADC connected to an FPGA based data acquisition board:

[image]

They don't have that FPGA in the middle for fun.

It is there because it has memory fast enough to capture data moving at 500 megabytes per second, and large enough to capture a useful amount of data.

It captures the data at full speed, then transfers it to the PC over USB - at much lower speed.

Your AD9601 can capture 250 million samples per second at 10 bits resolution.  You'll need two bytes to represent each value, so 500 megabytes per second.

I haven't the slightest idea whether or not your stm32 can handle data that fast, or hold enough to do anything useful.

Answer (score -1):

The AD9601 uses the SPI (Serial Peripheral Interconnect) protocol. This is a common interface requiring a clock, data and a chip select.  I note that the ADC9601 uses a bi-directional data line (SDIO). Typically a true SPI interface uses separate data-in and data-out.

The ST32F429 does include an SPI interface. You'll have to study the micro-controller documentation to determine exactly how to configure the SPI module.  The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f429ni.pdf) mentions the presence of the SPI module. The [reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) describes the SPI module in detail and describes how to program it.

Comment: Did you look at the datasheet? SPI is optional for configuration only. The parallel data port is 40 MSPS minimum, it does not work over SPI.

Comment: Oops. I failed to see the 40 MSPS min spec. This is a hot-rod ADC that seems to indicate the need for an FPGA interface.